# SCCM 2012 - Starting a program after MSI installation

Tags: wix, sccm

I have an msi installer for my program that is made using WIX.  One part of the installer runs my program after the installation is complete.

```
<CustomAction Id="Launch_MyProgram" FileKey="MyProgram" ExeCommand=""
    Return="asyncNoWait" Impersonate="yes" Execute="immediate" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="Launch_MyProgram" After="InstallFinalize">NOT Installed</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

This works fine to start up the program when I run the installer on my own machine.  However, we do our deployments using SCCM 2012 and when the installer runs through SCCM 2012 the program is not started after the install has completed.  This is a problem for me because when I update the program during the day I would like it to start up again for the user when the new version is installed.  Here are my SCCM deployment type settings:

[image: Deployment Type - Programs]

[image: Deployment Type - User Experience]

Does anyone know how to do this through SCCM 2012?

Comment: Are you using <Product Id="*" ... /> or <Product Id="{GUID}" ... />? I think if you use GUID, the Installed property is set on upgrades (minor upgrade) since the Product, as Windows sees it, is already installed. But I'm not 100% sure about this.

Comment: @BrianSutherland I am using the * for Product Id so it changes every time that I re-build.  Also, I'm not doing minor upgrades.  I do a full uninstall then install of the new version.

Comment: You can try running your install command from SCCP with /l*v log.txt appended and look through the log to see if it is skipping or executing the Launch_MyProgram action.

Comment: You should try another command line. After InstallFinalize with /qn might not run the custom action because you have an immediate CA that runs in the UI and you've suppressed UI with /qn.  Try /qb!  Or full UI as a test.

Comment: @PhilDW In my most recent deployment I ran it without any /q parameters and it still didn't startup the program.

Comment: Time for a verbose log, add /l*v [path to text log file]   to your command line.